# Pandas groupby to find percent True and False

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a column of sites: ['Canada', 'USA', 'China' ....]

Each site occurs many times in the SITE column and next to each instance is a true or false value.

```
INDEX | VALUE | SITE

0     | True  | Canada
1     | False | Canada
2     | True  | USA
3     | True  | USA
```

And it goes on.

**Goal 1: I want to find, for each site, what percent of the VALUE column is True.**

**Goal 2: I want to return a list of sites where % True in the VALUE column is greater than 10%.**

How do I use groupby to achieve this? I only know how to use groupby to find the mean for each site which won't help me here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like this:

```
In [13]: g = df.groupby('SITE')['VALUE'].mean()
In [14]: g[g > 0.1]
Out[14]: 
SITE
Canada    0.5
USA       1.0
```