# How to calculate perscentage from 2 column use pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i want to analyze a dataset like this

| id_employee | Department | awards_won? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 212 | Sales & Marketing | 0 |
| 213 | Operations | 1 |
| 214 | Technology | 1 |
| 215 | Operations | 0 |

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arashnic/hr-ana to see percentage employees who received awards in each department how to make in pandas ?
My final answer should look like:

| Department | awards_won? |
| --- | --- |
| Sales & Marketing | 10 % |
| Operations | 5 % |
| Technology | 7 % |

Comment: Please provide a [mre] directly in the question. Don't ask others to download a dataset from an external website. Also explain the logic, what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: use `groupby` + `mean`. If you want a more accurate answer, please provide sample data instead of linking to your file url, as @mozway commented.

Comment: refer to the following post when using `groupby` + `mean` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311211/pandas-groupby-to-find-percent-true-and-false

Comment: `df.groupby('department')['awards_won'].mean()`